# findViewByID() keeps returning null in custom View class

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my application I want to present the user with a little `DialogFragment` containing a `ListView` with two hard-coded items. These items are both instances of a custom `View` class i wrote called `PictureMethodOptionItem`.

A `PictureMethodOptionItem` contains of a `TextView` next to an `ImageView`.

- `picture_method_list.xml`:

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:stereovise="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/de.app.stereovise"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <de.app.stereovise.PictureMethodOptionItem
        android:id="@+id/listItemGallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        stereovise:optionType="gallery" />

    <de.app.stereovise.PictureMethodOptionItem
        android:id="@+id/listItemCamera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        stereovise:optionType="camera" />

</ListView>
```

- `picture_method_option.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="7dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/method_option_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/output"
        android:contentDescription="@string/methodOptionIcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/method_option_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/method_option_icon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/method_option_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And last but certainly not least the Java code of my custom `View` class:

`PictureMethodOptionItem.java`:

```
public class PictureMethodOptionItem extends View {

private Context context;

private ImageView methodIcon;
private TextView methodText;

public PictureMethodOptionItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;

    initialize();
    initFromAttributes(attrs);
}

public PictureMethodOptionItem(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;

    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_method_option, null, false);
    //View.inflate(context, R.layout.picture_method_option, null);

    methodIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.method_option_icon);
    methodText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.method_option_text);
    // at this point methodIcon and methodText are still null!
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();


}

private void initFromAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
    String type = attrs.getAttributeValue(
        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/de.app.stereovise",
        "optionType"
    );

    if("0".equals(type)) {
        methodIcon.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb);
        methodText.setText(R.string.methodGallery);
    } else {
        methodIcon.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        methodText.setText(R.string.methodCamera);
    }
}

}
```

The relevant code in which the `DialogFragment` gets inflated is from `PictureOptionsDialog.java`:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_method_list, null, false);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    builder
        .setTitle(R.string.pictureChoiceTitle)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setView(contentView);

    return builder.create();
}
```

The problem is now, that if I try to `show()` this Dialog it'll give me the following error:

```
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class de.app.stereovise.PictureMethodOptionItem
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at de.app.stereovise.PictureOptionsDialog.onCreateDialog(PictureOptionsDialog.java:22)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:295)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at de.app.stereovise.PictureMethodOptionItem.<init>(PictureMethodOptionItem.java:22)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    ... 20 more
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    at de.app.stereovise.PictureMethodOptionItem.initFromAttributes(PictureMethodOptionItem.java:55)
10-09 23:34:46.259: E/AndroidRuntime(14660):    ... 24 more
```

Hours of search only brought up solutions that either were already present in my code (such as overriding the `View` constructor that takes an `AttributeSet`) or aren't applicable in my case b/c they were pointing more towards Activities and their `setContentView()` methods.

Does anybody see the mistake(s) I made (probably very dull ones) and can tell me why the LayoutInflater has such a hard time inflating my little DialogFragment?

Comment: NullPointerException at de.app.stereovise.PictureMethodOptionItem.initFromAttributes(PictureMethodOptionItem.java:55) - What is line 55?  the call to methodIcon.set*?

Comment: Right, it's this line: `methodIcon.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb);`. As you can see in the comment, both methodIcon and methodText are null because findViewById() on them would always return null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call this method:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_method_option, null, false);
```

And you ignore the result. The last parameter, false, indicates to *not* add the content of the XML layout to the layout root (which you set to null anyway.) You need to do something like this:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_method_option, null, false);
addView(v);
```

Or:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_method_option, this, true);
```

Comment: Neither of these do the trick for me, sadly. When I change the boolean parameter to `true`, i get the exact same LogCat output and adding the View manually also doesn't work because there is no addView() method in the scope since I inherited `View`

Comment: Sorry I missed that. You *must* extend ViewGroup to have children.

Comment: I quickly did this change to extending ViewGroup and calling addView() after inflating it. However, the app still crashes with the aforementioned `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView`. My implementation of `onLayout` is currently an empty one. Right now I think I'm better off changing the Dialog such that it uses a ListAdapter which inflates these two views.

Comment: Right, so now the problem is different. Your custom class is working but you cannot add views directly to a ListView. You need to use an Adapter. You also probably don't need a ListView just for two items.

Comment: So, given that the ListView was a bad idea I changed it to LinearLayout and an exception no longer occurs. However, the dialog that pops up is empty but fills the entire screen, even when I set the LinearLayout's `layout_height` attribute to `wrap_content` (every other `layout_height` involved in this is `wrap_content` anyway). I suppose this may be the case due to my `onLayout()` method not being properly implemented, but since doing so seems like overkill I will now start solving my problem using a ListAdapter attached to the `DialogBuilder`. Thanks everyone